# Roman numerical generator

Tags: javascript, roman-numerals

I was trying to come up with a roman numerical generator in Javascript and I found this on Stack Overflow. I passes all tests but I cannot figure out how it works. I would really appreciate a nice description what is going on in this code:

```
let romanNumeralGenerator = (number) => {
    return 'I'
        .repeat(number)
        .replace(/I{5}/g, 'V')
        .replace(/V{2}/g, 'X')
        .replace(/X{5}/g, 'L')
        .replace(/L{2}/g, 'C')
        .replace(/C{5}/g, 'D')
        .replace(/D{2}/g, 'M')
        .replace(/DC{4}/g, 'CM')
        .replace(/C{4}/g, 'CD')
        .replace(/LX{4}/g, 'XC')
        .replace(/X{4}/g, 'XL')
        .replace(/VI{4}/g, 'IX')
        .replace(/I{4}/g, 'IV')
};
```

Comment: If you have found this on SO then explanation must be there.

Comment: Please provide attribution for code you've copied from elsewhere on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually fairly simple to explain.

the method `romanNumeralGenerator()` takes in a number as an argument, let's take the number `10` for example.  The `repeat()` method will repeat the string that it present the number of times specified, in our case 10 times.  So when the number `10` is passed into our function it will repeat `I` 10 times creating the string `IIIIIIIIII`.

Then the function takes the resulting string and performs the `replace` method given the matching regular expression.  In our case it will hit the first regex and see that we have at least 5 repeating `I's`, so it will convert them into a `V` giving us the string `VIIIII`.  It will recognize another string of 5 repeating `I's` and convert them to a `V` as well resulting in the string `VV`.  After that it will match the second regex and notice that there are 2 `V's` present, which will convert the string to `X`, giving us the correct roman numeral for the number `10` that we passed into the function.  Hope this helps.